# How to set the height of the div to vertical space of the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div which should occupy the remaining vertical space of the browser window. If the content in that div is maximum than the height of the div, it should add scroll bar for that div.

I'm tried something similar to this, but it is of no use

```
h = $(document).height();
$("#mydiv").attr(height : h);
```

Comment: what do you mean vertical space?.. dont you just need overflow-y:auto; on that div in your css?... and give that div height:100% in your css too

Comment: vertical space = remaining empty vertical space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
h = $(document).height();
$("#mydiv").css('height', h);
```

Comment: css property -  'overflow:scroll;' needs to be added i guess along with this.

Comment: Is there any special advantage of using the css setter here? And not the `$.height` method directly?

Comment: To me...using CSS makes it clear where the property comes from.  Using $(document).height() doesn't make it clear that you are affecting a CSS attribute and creates confusion amongst new programmers as to what is being updated.

Comment: The guy needs the remaining space so h should be diff of the total space and the current starting position of the div

Answer (score 1):

you need the window height :)

```
$(window).height()
```

like so:

```
$("#mydiv").height($(window).height());
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use either $(window).height() or $(document).height() depending on which is interesting for you.

Height is not a DOM attribute, it is a CSS attribute. But it is nicely abstracted into the height() function so you can use it for setting aswell.

```
var height_to_set = $(document).height();
$("#mydiv").height(height_to_set);
```